# Facebook: How to pass information between pages

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, session

I've been following the guide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Once I have the server-side flow section working and have access to the accounts information is the idea to then store that information in my database and create a session for the user?  That way they can log in and out of my site?

If not, how does my site access the user's information and log the user out when needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i check if the user is already saved in the DB, if not i create the users account and then save the info in the session (login the user on my site).

I prefer to use the [php SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/) provided, because it's easier to call the fb api, and i mix it with the Javascript SDK, to show the login buttons and pop-up... also for the like buttons

Good Luck

Comment: Right now I have it so I do what you mentioned just haven't made a session for the user yet. Thanks for the info! :)